# Does WAS Liberty 8.5.5.7 Support mail-resource configurations?

Tags: java, email, websphere-liberty

I just recently installed WAS Liberty 8.5.5.7 as I am doing a conversion to Liberty for a projected presently deployed and configured for a GlassFish 4 environment.

The glassfish project, has a `<mail-resource>` configured within its domain configuration which the application utilizes to send out outgoing emails.

I was hoping the WAS Liberty supported such a configuration, can anyone clarify
as I have not found any such documentation?

Answer (score 1):

WAS Liberty 8.5.5.6 included full support for Java EE7 (including JavaMail 1.5).

There is no `<mail-resource>` element in WAS Liberty (it's probably some Glassfish specific config element that is not spec-standard).

Instead, you can configure javaMail like this once you enable the `javaMail-1.5` feature:

```
<mailSession    mailSessionID="examplePop3MailSession"  
        jndiName="ExampleApp/POP3Servlet/exampleMailSession"
        description="POP3 javax.mail.Session"
        storeProtocol="pop3"
        transportProtocol="smtp"
        host="exampleserver.com"
        user="iamanexample@example.com"
        password="example"
        from="smtp@testserver.com">
     <property name="mail.pop3.host" value="pop3.example.com" />
     <property name="mail.pop3.port" value="3110" />
</mailSession>
```

[See official documentation from IBM on configuring Java Mail 1.5](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_javamail.html).

Comment: Thank-you so much aguibert ... may I ask .. also in the same line of questioning ... does WAS Liberty have an equivalent configuration for <system-properties> and <resource-ref> as I have such configurations in my current glassfish server and need to convert them into the WAS Liberty environment? Thank-you kindly

Comment: The `<resource-ref>` is a config element defined by the Java EE spec, so yes Liberty supports this.  For `<system-properties>` you can set those instead using the `server.env` file (for details see https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html).

Comment: I have yet to fully get this to work, but once I do I will update for certain.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile Guide for Developers](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248076.html?Open). In chapter 5 you will find sample application and step by step configuration how to use mail session with Liberty.